Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected... Still attempting to connect to the VM Service... only in iOS
I need to run a Flutter app on iOS, but get the following error:
Xcode build done.                                           52.1s
Connecting to the VM Service is taking longer than expected...
Still attempting to connect to the VM Service...
If you do NOT see the Flutter application running, it might have crashed. The device logs (e.g. from adb or XCode) might have more details.
If you do see the Flutter application running on the device, try re-running with --host-vmservice-port to use a specific port known to be available.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 53392
This was attempt #50. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 53566

How can I fix this?

I have a similar issue
